# How to Determine Checked State of Checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, checkbox, windows-phone-8

I have a checkboxes in a page. I am not sure which event I should be using to examine the checked state. I need to determine if the checkbox is either checked or unchecked. What is the proper method for this? I have seen in researching that the Checkbox actually has three states; Checked, Unchecked, and Indeterminate. This is confusing me as it would seem that only two states will occur to the user. From a user's perspective, the Checkbox will either be Checked or Unchecked, but from my perspective, how do I handle this with the three states? Am I understanding this correctly? Also, what event should I use? Other considerations?

Essentially what I am trying to do is ask the user whether they want to show landmarks on the new map control for WP8. If so, I need to save this setting and also I will limit the map's zoom (which I will do in another area). I just need to determine the user's preference from the checkbox control and save his or her settings. What I have is as follows thus far

```
<CheckBox x:Name="LandmarksEnabledCheckBox" Checked="LandmarksEnabledCheckBox_Checked">
                        <CheckBox.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPage_LandmarksEnabled, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </CheckBox.Content>
                    </CheckBox>

private void LandmarksEnabledCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //If CheckBox is checked, set `Settings.LandmarksEnabled.Value = true`, otherwise false
        //??
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CheckBox has IsChecked property which is a nullable bool, in other words

```
bool?
```

You could just check if the CheckBox has value, and if it has, take it and compare to true or false.

```
if (LandmarksEnabledCheckBox.IsChecked.HasValue)
{
    if (LandmarksEnabledCheckBox.IsChecked.Value == true)
    {
        //checkbox is checked
    }
    else
    {
        //checkbox is not checked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple

```
bool SuperAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(chkbx_SuperAdmin.CheckState);
```

it will get you the current state of the check box.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

CheckBoxes are a `ToggleButton` in WPF. As such, they have an `IsChecked` property.

```
if (checkBox.IsChecked)
```

Comment: Ok. I'm working with Windows Phone 8, it also has that property. I assumed I should check this on some even that fires when the checked state changes. Unfortunately WP8 has no CheckChanged event. Are you saying I should use the IsChecked event?

Comment: @Matthew IsChecked is a property. There's a Checked event which fires when the CheckBox gets checked - you're already using it up there in your code. There's also Unchecked event, which fires when the CheckBox is unchecked.

Comment: ```bool SuperAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(chkbx_SuperAdmin.CheckState);``` worked but ```if (checkBox.IsChecked) ``` didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checkBox.Checked)
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, as the property is `IsChecked`, and that property is a nullable bool. `Checked` is an event that fires when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  bool check = Boolean.Parse(LandmarksEnabledCheckBox.IsChecked.ToString());
  if (check)
   {

   }
```